# Can't pass file handle to subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I created a file in the current directory with `echo "foo" > foo`. I then tried to pass that file to `subprocess.run`, but I seem to misunderstand how file paths are handled in Python, since I'm getting an error. What's wrong?

My test code

```
with open('foo') as file:
    import subprocess
    subprocess.run(['cat',file])
```

yields

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

What is a `PathLike` object? How to I get it from `open('foo')`? Where can I find more information about how files are handled in Python?

Comment: It requires a *string-like* or `PathLike` object. Just pass it `'foo'`. Why are you `open`ing the file, anyway?

Comment: In contrast to "path like", there's so called ["file like" objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) (like the one you tried to pass to `subprocess.run()`). In short, those are file handles that allow you to operate on files (or streams, generally speaking) *from inside Python*, with methods like `read()` and `write()`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to open the file in the first place. You can simply run

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['cat', 'foo'])
```

The `cat` command is being run as a shell command by your machine, so you should just be able to pass the file name as a string.

Python does not handle the file at all. The point of subprocess is to pass a command to the underlying system (in this case, apparently a UNIX based OS). All you are doing is passing a plaintext command to the command line.

I won't, however, discourage you from reading about file handling. Look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

PathLike object: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.PathLike)

How to get it from the [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) call's [return value](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object):

Use the `name` field

```
subprocess.run(['cat',file.name])
```

Learn about python files: [Reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)